# How to add ranking to each returned item ordered by specific field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a ranking system for my book collection ordered by award count and below is the result returns from my database

```
    {
        'awardCount' : 12000,
        'year' : 1967,
        'by' : 'IEEE Computer Society'
    }, 
    {
        'awardCount' : 11230,
        'year' : 1993,
        'by' : 'National Academy of Engineering'
    }, 
    {
        'awardCount' : 10600,
        'year' : 1993,
        'by' : 'National Academy of Engineering'
    }
........about 10000+ more and sorted by awardCount
```

I use this query to get the result above

```
.find()
.sort({awardCount: -1 })
```

my question is if it is possible to have add 'rank' field in each item to show ranking order? For example

```
  {
        'awardCount' : 12000,
        'year' : 1967,
        'by' : 'IEEE Computer Society',
        'rank': 1

    },
    {
        'awardCount' : 11230,
        'year' : 1993,
        'by' : 'National Academy of Engineering',
        'rank': 2
    }
```

if not, what would be the best solution to get ranking in this situation? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you want to add rank? It is not possible to add custom field with an index... Why I am 100% sure because I asked the same question yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870664/concat-field-with-index-in-map-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment88744122_50870664.. you can add if you put limit in it but that would be more complicated and costly

Comment: I want to have the ranking of the book that's why I need rank.

Comment: You can only do this at the time of inserting the documents... and the rest I told you on the above comments

Answer (score 0):

you could use **mongodb aggregate** to achieve this.You basically sort the documents by wins and kills and then push each user in a new array while preserving the index, this index is the users' rank after that you can simply use 'unwind' on this newly created array and find the user in question, this will give you the user's rank with other details.

Here is a sample aggregate pipeline:

```js
[{
    "$sort": { 
        "awardCount": -1
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": false,
        "books": {
            "$push": {
                "_id": "$_id",
                "by": "$by",
                "year": "$year",
                "awardCount": "$awardCount"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$books",
        "includeArrayIndex": "rank"
    }
}]
```